# Example Content-Types for `POST` validation failures?

Tags: validation, http, rest

Suppose an HTTP server responds to a `POST` with a 400 response code because the request failed validation (e.g. email address not found).  If the server wishes to provide more information to the client about the nature of the error, how should this be returned?  For each possible content type used in requests, should there ideally be an associated "error" content type?

For example, given the request

```
POST /users
Content-Type: application/x-myuser

{
    "email": "foo@example.com",
    "name": "Michael"
}
```

a response might be

```
400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/x-myuser-error

{
    "email": "Email address foo@example.com not found"
}
```

Are there any good examples of "error" content types publicly available?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any examples, but it's good to always keep these in mind:

- Always include a machine-readable error, and generalize as much as possible. A JSON structure like

  `{"error":"Email address not found!","code":"fielderror","field":"email","reason":"notfound"}` (could be simplified to `{"error":"...","code":"emailnotfound"}`)

  allows API developers to properly present the error to the user (and act on the error) while it allows you to change the messages without breaking applications. It also really helps with translation of error messages, both on your end and the external developer's end.
- A different approach is to simply don't return any body, and use HTTP headers to tell the user agent what went wrong. For example, you could use `X-Error` and `X-Error-Code` to show a human readable error, and a machine readable code.
- Creating too many content types might be a bad thing. I personally prefer to always use `application/json` and let the user agent know the status by looking at the HTTP codes: 200, 400, 403, 404, 500, etc.
- Definitely don't ever start making combinations of HTTP codes and content types. You don't want your users to have to learn that `application/myapp/error` means there's an error, UNLESS it's 200 in which case you're in the edit screen, OR when it's 302 it's not actually an error but a redirect. This is why you should probably stick with one content type.

Bottom line: always keep it simple. Make sure that there's **one** field which you have to look at, not two or three, when detecting a status. Once the user agent has determined the status it could choose to look at some other fields for extra info, but only after it has determined that something went wrong. Including a separate content type probably won't help there.

Comment: If your response includes a custom Content-Type header, you wouldn't have to guess that the `error` field includes the machine-readable error though--that would be guaranteed by the MIME type. Without it, you're assuming that an `application/json` response to a particular status code/URL combination can be interpreted in a particular way, which doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: You're forgetting about the HTTP status code. 200 means everything went fine, 3xx means redirect, and 4xx or 5xx means you should check for an error. It's that simple, really.

Comment: I'm not ignoring the status code, but I don't see how it helps a client in interpreting a server's response. In your original answer you provide examples of two different validation failed responses. As a consumer, how do you know which style the server returned? Wouldn't the Content-Type be a good way to determine this, in the same way that `image/png` tells a consumer how to interpret binary data?

Comment: Let me put this in [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) terms then. You SHOULD use the response codes as the primary way of identifying the status of the request. You MAY use the Content-Type header to help parsers properly understand the response.